# How can I run Spring app?

Tags: java, spring

I do not konw how to run Spring app.
I made & edit app whose name is My app in IntelliJ and I wanna run it.
In directory of Myapp,I wrote a command

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

&run,terminal said

```
zsh: command not found: mvn
```

Furthermore,I put Run button of IntelliJ,but there was no Run button(there is only 0.Edit Configuration).
I use Spring framework,how can I run my app?

Comment: If you are using `IntelliJ` then go the class where you have `main()` method. Then click anywhere inside main method. Click right button and rum main method. By the way this is not a good way. This just for your test.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) in your environment.